# Bind jQuery plugin to live element

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, bind

Just a simple question, but I cannot seem to bind a plugin function to a live element that was cloned.

```
$('.add-another').live('click', function()
{
   var self = $(this);
   var clonedElement = self.parents('.row').clone();

   clonedElement.find('input.datepicker').bind('click', function()
   {
       $(this).datepick({ rangeSelect: true });
   });
});
```

I'm using [this](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html) plugin (I'm not using jQueryUI nor it's datepicker). So how can I bind a plugin function to a cloned/live element?

**EDIT:** Here's a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qZn8d/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're binding to an id (#add-another). The standard says that there can be only one element with a given ID at any time.

So, this won't really work as intended. Change the id to a class(i.e. the # to an .) and try again :)

Another possible problem may be that the HTML simply doesn't have the structure you expect it to and some of the queries are failing. We'd be able to debug that if you post the HTML structure :)

**Edit**:
You were binding to the "click" event, which was actually wrong - you can create the datepicker at the same time you create the HTML element.

Here's the new code:

```
$('.row input.datepicker').datepick({ rangeSelect: true });

$('span.add-another').live('click', function()
{
    var self = $(this);
    var clone = self.parents('.row').clone();

    $('input.datepicker', clone).datepick({ rangeSelect: true });
    $(clone).insertAfter(self.parents('.row')).hide().slideDown('fast');

    self.remove();
});
```

Also, I have bad news for you - the datepicker plugin is broken :)
The datepicker itself seems to only be able to show **one** datepicker on a page.
You should either research how to show several, or just use jQueryUI.

As you can see, here only the original object has a datepicker: http://jsfiddle.net/qZn8d/7/
And here only the *first* added object has a datepicker: http://jsfiddle.net/qZn8d/6/

So, yeah, the plugin is broken, sorry :)

Comment: Oops, my mistake. I've changed it to a class, but it clones successfully but does not work with the datepicker function, even I've used a single non-live element, and it works just fine but not having a cloned element doesn't seem to show any datepicker.

Comment: Can you make a minimal jsfiddle demo of the behaviour? It would make it easier to debug. http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to bind a function to a cloned object which is not yet in the DOM. Insert it in the dom

OR

Use live instead of bind with cloned object